# День (П,п)обеды, если о празднике в других государствах

Tags: орфография

Новостной заголовок "В Украине хотят перенести День Победы".

Речь о том, что на Украине (якобы!) хотят перенести праздник на 8-е число. Но на Украине этот праздник называется День победы [над нацизмом...] — "день" со строчной. Понятно, что перенести могут хотеть не российский праздник, а их собственный. Какие основания для заглавной в этом случае?

Comment: "День"-то с заглавной, это "победы" у них со строчной. А вопрос интересный...

Comment: День с большой. А победы у них с маленькой. А зачем мне вопрос изменили? Я говорю о государстве Украина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В украинском (и в украинском русском) не только свои названия, но и свои законы (хотя в части использования заглавных они совпадают). Я думаю, что здесь название праздника надо не механически переносить, а именно **переводить**, то есть использовать принятые в русском правила и соглашения. То есть "День Победы в/на Украине" вполне оправдано. Здесь нет неуважения к традициям или какой-то политизированности, это чисто лингвистические соображения.

Хотя понимаю и тех, кто будет протестовать против навязывания своих болот чужому кулику. Но мы все-таки пишем на русском и пренебрежение его орфографическими нормами раздражает куда больше всех языковых толерантностей вместе взятых (элементарно **Ва**тсон, это же Бел**а**русь). Но вообще вопрос при долгом обсуждении обязательно съедет в политику, так что я закругляюсь.

Answer (score 0):

**День Победы (победы)** — праздник, отмечаемый в ряде стран мира и обычно посвящённый победе в каком-либо сражении или войне:

*27—28 апреля — Афганистан: **День победы** афганского народа в джихаде (1992)

8 мая — США и ряд стран Европы: День Победы в Европе (1945)

9 мая — СССР/Россия и ряд других стран: День Победы (1945)

**9 мая — Украина: День победы над нацизмом во Второй мировой войне**

23 июня — Эстония: День Победы в Освободительной войне (1919)

5 августа — Хорватия: **День победы** и благодарности отчизне (1995)*
[**День Победы**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Каждая страна сама решает: с какой - прописной или строчной - буквы пишется слово "победа".
 **День Победы** (без пояснения: над кем? в чём?..) *может быть только один, единственный, особенный, самый важный - тот, который понятен всегда и всем жителям государства. Таков **День Победы в России.***
Есть и другой: *День воинской славы России — **День победы** в Сталинградской битве в 1943 году.*

Возможно, в Украине есть более "особенные" дни победы? Возможно, у правительства Незалежной другое видение и оценка Победы.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Вы, боюсь, не поняли. День-то один и тот же, и смысл почти тот же (разве что у них более широко, во всей ***Второй мировой*** и без упоминания Германии), но называют они его на свой лад. Можно, конечно, до хрипоты спорить, не принижает ли там роль СССР и проч., но было бы как минимум странно требовать формулировки названия государственного праздника, исходящей из традиций другого государства. Перенести его хотят, видимо, на 8-е - по европейской традиции.

Comment: Но речь не о том. Как назвать этот праздник правильно, вне зависимости от того, ругаем мы их или хвалим. Это вопрос орфографии, а не политики. Хотя, я и подозревал, что он  очень подвержен политизации.

Comment: Мне кажется, что я поняла всё правильно: "Верховная Рада Украины в 2015 году приняла закон "Об увековечении победы над нацизмом во Второй мировой войне 1939-1945 годов", который установил 8 мая Днем памяти и примирения, а вместо советского праздника "День Победы" был установлен День победы над нацизмом во Второй мировой войне, который ежегодно будет отмечаться 9 мая.
Полный текст читайте здесь: https://www.rbc.ua/rus/news/ukraina-segodnya-otmechaet-den-pobedy-natsizmom-1462777798.html

Comment: *Мне кажется, что я поняла всё правильно* - цитируете вы правильно. Но пишете нечто противоречащее этой цитате. *Возможно, в Украине есть более "особенные" дни победы?*.

Answer (score 0):

Давать название своим праздникам - суверенное право каждой страны. Украина  решила, что праздник, который раньше назывался *День Перемоги* (оба слова с большой буквы), теперь будет называться *День перемо́ги над наци́змом у Дру́гій світові́й війні́*  или коротко *День перемо́ги* (второе слово со строчной).

Может ли Украина определять, как название этого праздника будет переведено на русский? Не думаю. И, думаю, не нам решать, как правильно перевести новое название. Наверное, есть в России орган, который устнавливает стандарты на этот счет, например решает, как должны выглядеть те или иные иностранные названия в русском переводе.